# Getting Goroutine deadlock when using for loop to traverse through the channel

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am tring to practise goroutine and channels, where I am facing issue where I am calling gorouting and passing channel. The goroutine will push data into into channel and then main thread will print the elements.

I have used for loop to print the contents but getting.

```sh
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

2
1
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
```

```golang
package main

import "fmt"


func smallThread(a int, c chan int) {
    c <- a
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go smallThread(1, c)
    go smallThread(2, c)
    for {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Using waitgroup:

```golang
func smallThread(a int, c chan int, w *sync.WaitGroup) {
    c <- a
    w.Done()
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    var w sync.WaitGroup
    w.Add(2)
    go smallThread(1, c, &w)
    go smallThread(2, c, &w)
    //w.Wait()
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
    w.Wait()
}
```

**EDIT2**: Working Code

```golang
func smallThread(a int, c chan int, w *sync.WaitGroup) {
    //defer w.Done()
    c <- a
    w.Done()
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    var w sync.WaitGroup
    w.Add(1)
    go smallThread(1, c, &w)
    w.Add(1)
    go smallThread(2, c, &w)
    go func(c chan int) {
        for i := range c {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }(c)
    w.Wait()
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729643/golang-how-can-i-stop-the-execution-of-a-for-loop-from-outside-the-loop/37732256#37732256, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54339304/all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock-with-waitgroup, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166296/one-channel-with-one-receiver-and-unknown-number-of-goroutines-senders-causing-d, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603716/best-time-to-close-channel-when-iterating-over-channel/56604063#56604063, etc,

Comment: There's no guarantee that the "Edit 2" version will print the values before the program exits.

Comment: Please tell me why?

Comment: @JeYa: because main exits when waitgroup is finished. Nothing in the code waits for reader goroutine to finish reading the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the goroutines are done, close the channel to indicate that no more values will be added. The for loop will break when after all values are received.

```
c := make(chan int)
var w sync.WaitGroup
w.Add(2)
go smallThread(1, c, &w)
go smallThread(2, c, &w)
go func() {
    w.Wait()
    close(c)
}()

for i := range c {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Comment: When I am adding `w.Wait()` before the goroutine, after `go smallThread(2, c, &w)`, I am getting deadlock error, I wanted to wait the main thread unless all the `smallThread` are finished

Comment: @JeYa Because the channel is unbuffered,  the `smallThread` goroutines do not complete until after the main goroutine receives.  If the main goroutine calls w.Wait() before receiving, the `smallThread` goroutines block on send. If the goroutines block on send, then they never call w.Done().  That's a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is, but I'll tell you what happens. Your two side goroutines push their numbers to the channel and exit. Then the main goroutine (the only one left at this point) will block forever, waiting for another element to come out of the channel.

Comment: How can I handle this?

Comment: @JeYa: depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I trying to learn goroutine pushing data into same channel and main thread or any other thread traversing over it

Comment: @JeYa: I'd say, that goal is achieved. You successfully push data to a channel from one goroutine and another reads it.

Comment: @JeYa: I explained that in the answer.

Comment: One way to prevent a goroutine from blocking on reading from a channel that nobody writes to is to close that channel. A waitgroup will indeed be handy here, to wait for all writers to exit before closing the channel.

Comment: I have added another code using waitgroup. Please review and let me know where I am going. Thanks for promt reply :)

Comment: @JeYa: no, don't do that. If you have a working code, post as an answer. And check out Cerise's version.